# SslStream AuthenticateAsClient using PFX file

Tags: ssl, sslstream

I'm trying to connect to a server using an SslStream.  I've been given a PFX file from the owner of the server and I've installed it on my client but I'm not sure how to access the certificate from my code.

Specifically, imagine that I have the following code...

```
var serverName = "?";
var stream = new SslStream();
stream.AuthenticateAsClient(serverName);
```

What would the value of serverName be?  I've tried
  the IP address of the server
  "MyServer"
  "CN = MyServer"

None of these values seem to work.  Is there something additional I need to do to access the cert store on my machine, or do I not understand what the serverName needs to be?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

It must be the Common Name (CN - which is usually a [fully qualified domain name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name)) of the *servers certificates subject* for the host you are connecting to.

For example if the servers certificates subject looks like:

```
CN = www.verisign.com, OU = Production Security Services, O = VeriSign, Inc ...
```

you should use:

```
stream.AuthenticateAsClient("www.verisign.com");
```

If the host you are connecting to allows connections without client certificate verification then you should be able to connect to it (with a browser for example - if HTTPS) and see the server certificate, or you can try using [OpenSSL client](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html).